# How to get boolean value, If element id clicked - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get boolean value, if element id has been clicked in angular. I have tried to get boolean value through document.getElementById to find element clicked or not, but that is not working as expected.

This is how my sample html code:

```
<button id="my-btn-id" class="bx--number__control-btn up-icon">
```

If my button id will be clicked, I need to get true or need to return false. Here through click event I can able to get it, but I need to be identified through id. If any one have any idea please help me.

Comment: If it is angular then go angular way...But in most cases you don't need id for such scenarios. If you could explain bit more about your issue then suggesting any answer would become easier.

Comment: isn't stopping the form submission would get it solved? Can you add your form sumission code also in your post?

Comment: @Jai Yeah I got it...Through event listener I can get element id and problem resolved..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a add a variable in your class, say: `public myBtnIdClicked: boolean = false`

```
<button id="my-btn-id" (click)="myBtnIdClicked = true" class="bx--number__control-btn up-icon">
```

Add a click listener on your button, set the variable `myBtnIdClicked` to true once a click happens over the button.

Comment: Sorry haha as i posted answer saw yours 48 seconds before. like the thinking though

Comment: @dince12 haha, yeah it happens :)

Comment: @SpRaju I didn't fully understand you comment. Please update your question with all the requirements. Also do mean the button to be not used as a submit button when you hit Enter? If yes then give a type to the button, like: `<button type="button" .....rest of the attributes>`

Comment: @xyz Yeah I got it...Through event listener I can get element id and problem resolved..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not exactly what you want but why not keep it simple. I like simple.

**controller**

```
public clickedBtn1: boolean = false; // keep a number which is the same as button id.
```

Then you can always check by simply.

```
if (this.clickedBtn1)
{
     //do something 
     // will only be reached if button has been clicked
}
```

**template**

```
<button id="1" class="bx--number__control-btn up-icon" (click)="clickedBtn1 = true">
```